# javascript window.open not working in safari and chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, safari, onclick

I have a div element.
The div is an icon.
When you click on this icon is triggered a form submit.
On the form submit there are some calculations and with the result of those calculations a new tab is opened.

I use the "**window.open(url, '_blank');**"

But in safari and chrome this new tab is seen as a popup and is blocked.

I tried to create a hidden a href and to trigger click so it will open the page in new tab, but it doesn't work.

Any idea how to fix this?

**EDIT - SOLUTION FOUND**

You need to add the window.open on a click event inside an $.ajax success method. In this way it will work.

```
$('#myButton').click(function () {
    var redirectWindow = window.open('http://google.com', '_blank');
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/echo/json/',
        success: function (data) {
            redirectWindow.location;
        }
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/safeeronline/70kdacL4/1/

Comment: If people want to block popups, they will block popups, there's not a huge amount you can do besides adding a visible hyperlink that the user needs to click on to see the results, as **direct user interaction** leading to a popup will not generally be blocked.

Comment: Try this it is showing  in safari & chrom                                          
 `<html>
  <head>
    <!--Load the AJAX API-->
 </head>
 <body>
 
 <input type=button onclick="Test()" value="Click me">
 
 <script>
   function Test(){
   window.open("https://nodejs.org", '_self/_blank');}
  </script>
</body>
</html>`

Comment: add your onclick code... are you doing the window.open directly there?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you need to call window.open as a direct result of a onclick event (user event)... you can't do something before async, and then on a result of that do the window.open

Comment: Your solution works great! But how do i make it so that the window will only open after the insert query is done? Because it can't capture the id yet because the table is empty and the query for printing the report is happening faster than executing the insert query.