# Javascript window.open issue in safari

Tags: jquery, safari

I am tying to open new tab using jquery. But, it's not working in safari or Mac.

**My code:**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            dataType: 'html',
            url:'http://localhost/test/remoteContent.html',
            async: false,
            success:function(data){
                window.open("http:google.com",'_blank');
            }

        })
    });
</script>
```

Comment: debug and check whether your success function is called or not

Comment: I have alert after success its works

Comment: Refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/44181104/8317956

Comment: @slacker I have used async: false, because browser is preventing pop-up

Comment: Possible duplicate of [javascript window.open not working in safari and chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44180931/javascript-window-open-not-working-in-safari-and-chrome)

Comment: @BoffinbraiN if I want to open after ajax response. Its not proper answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found alternate solution for this. After ajax response create anchor tag element and trigger click event

```
 var a = document.createElement('a');
 a.href = 'https://google.com';
 a.setAttribute('target', '_blank');
 a.click();
```

Answer (score 5):

I know it's not the answer you want, but unfortunately this is how modern browser security works. Due to the way popups and other actions can be abused to do 'bad things' on web pages, things like `click` for File Upload form fields and `window.open` in other cases will *only* work when the user has explicitly performed an action. These are known as [trusted events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/isTrusted) and cannot be spoofed by JavaScript. I have read up on this before, and you should find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29873845/534406) to be very informative.

You'll have to modify your workflow so that the tab opens after the user has clicked something, or open a new tab as part of the initial operation.