# Implementing a download servlet for iPad

Tags: javascript, java, servlets, download, anchor

I have implemented a downloader servlet using java as stated:

[Implementing a simple file download servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1442893/implementing-a-simple-file-download-servlet)

The requirement is, on the browser side, the file should be automatically downloaded, not triggered by any anchor click. On the ajax response, I call

```
document.location = "downloadServlet?fileId=foo"
```

The problem is, it works fine for all desktop browsers, android mobile devices.
But when the device is a iPad tablet, both chrome and safari do not download the file, for example if the file is a text file, the content is dumped to the page and my working page is lost. How can I force that the file is downloaded and not the content is shown? Even if trying a zip file for example, then the browser of tablet shows a different page and corrupts the working page. What I want is the browser downloads it as if performed SaveAs for all types of files.

Because the document.location changes the whole page on the iPad, I changed it to an anchor, but because it should be triggered automatically, I trigger the click event by

```
<a href="downloadServlet?.." target="_blank" rel="noopener" id="downloadAnchor" />

document.getElementById("downloadAnchor").click()
```

But then the popup blockers prevent the click event.

Comment: In your servlet, try setting the response header Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=myfilename.myext

Comment: Hi, I already added that but not working for iPad even if setting the disposition to attachment, when you download a text file its content is directly put to the initial page

Comment: I tried all options https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6520231/how-to-force-browser-to-download-file but ipad+safari always opens the content on the current tab. Opening a new tab/window is not possible due popup blocking mechanism of safari. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44180931/javascript-window-open-not-working-in-safari-and-chrome does not help because the file is generated dynamically and we are not sure that we will download a file when clicking the link (business rule)

Comment: Try setting the content-type response header as application/octet-stream mime type

Comment: ı tried application/octet-stream, force-download, x-download but ipad always shows in the same page without saveas.